# Extracting pixel values by overlaying polygons

Tags: classification, rasterio, overlay, pixel

I am trying to extract pixel values by overlaying polygons. I use a code after Patrick Grey (http://patrickgray.me/open-geo-tutorial/chapter_5_classification.html). When I masked the image with the shape features I got **out_image**. Then the next step is removing 0, which totally mess up the array as values are not present according bands. I have been coding only for a month and I tried many ways to remove 0 and keep the order of band values according class. In R I can do it without any problem and when I export the data as CSV and train the algorithm everything works fine in Python environment.

How can I extract pixel values and keep the numbers band and class-wise?

```
    X = np.array([], dtype=np.int8).reshape(0,8) # pixels for training
    y = np.array([], dtype=np.string_) # labels for training

   with rasterio.open(img_fp) as src:
        band_count = src.count
        for index, geom in enumerate(geoms):
            feature = [mapping(geom)]

    # the mask function returns an array of the raster pixels within this feature
    out_image, out_transform = mask(src, feature, crop=True) 
    # eliminate all the pixels with 0 values for all 8 bands - AKA not actually part of the shapefile
    out_image_trimmed = out_image[:,~np.all(out_image == 0, axis=0)]
    # eliminate all the pixels with 255 values for all 8 bands - AKA not actually part of the shapefile
    out_image_trimmed = out_image_trimmed[:,~np.all(out_image_trimmed == 255, axis=0)]
    # reshape the array to [pixel count, bands]
    out_image_reshaped = out_image_trimmed.reshape(-1, band_count)
    # append the labels to the y array
    y = np.append(y,[shapefile["Classname"][index]] * out_image_reshaped.shape[0]) 
    # stack the pizels onto the pixel array
    X = np.vstack((X,out_image_reshaped))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is to solution. I had to slice up the data band wise then transpose it and stack it by columns. After this step **np.vstack** worked and everything is in order.

```
 X = np.array([], dtype=np.int8).reshape(0,9) # pixels for training
 y = np.array([], dtype=np.int8) # labels for training

 # extract the raster values within the polygon 
with rio.open(sentinal_band_paths[7]) as src:
    band_count = src.count
    for index, geom in enumerate(geoms):
    feature = [mapping(geom)]

    # the mask function returns an array of the raster pixels within this feature
    out_image, out_transform = mask(src, feature, crop=True) 
    # eliminate all the pixels with 0 values for all 8 bands - AKA not actually part of the shapefile
    out_image_trimmed = out_image[:,~np.all(out_image == 0, axis=0)]
    # eliminate all the pixels with 255 values for all 8 bands - AKA not actually part of the shapefile
    out_image_trimmed = out_image_trimmed[:,~np.all(out_image_trimmed == 255, axis=0)]
    # reshape the array to [pixel count, bands]
    out_image_reshaped = out_image_trimmed.reshape(-1, band_count)
    # reshape the array to [pixel count, bands]
    trial = np.split(out_image_trimmed, 9)##### share it to equally after bands
    B1 = trial[0].T ####transpons columns
    B2 = trial [1].T
    B3 = trial [2].T
    B4 = trial [3].T
    B5 = trial [4].T
    B6= trial [5].T
    B7 = trial [6].T
    B8 = trial [7].T      
    B9 = trial[8].T
    colum_data = np.column_stack((B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9))####concatenate data colum wise 
    # append the labels to the y array
    y = np.append(y,[shapefile["id"][index]] *  out_image_reshaped.shape[0]) 
    # stack the pizels onto the pixel array
    X = np.vstack((X,colum_data ))
```